# Perl - unwanted whitespace characters inserted

Tags: regex, perl, removing-whitespace

I am experiencing a strange problem that I cannot make sense of: Perl is adding a space after tab character that I print. The data is being read from a tab-delimited file supplied to me by a collaborator. The data is being read and processed by the following code:

```
my $file = shift @ARGV;
my @g;
open (FILE, $file);
while (<FILE>) {
    my $line = $_;
    chomp $line;
    my @fields = split("\t", $line);
    push(@g, $fields[2]);
    push(@g, $fields[5]);
    push(@g, $fields[7]);
    ...
}
```

My first thought was that I might have a hidden whitespace character at the start of my variables so I tried several methods of removing using Regex to no noticeable effect. The code snippets below have behaved the same way regardless of how I modified the code that acts upon the contents of @g:

```
# DEBUGGING
foreach (@g) { print "$_"; }
exit;
```

which printed:

```
catdoghatchairpen
```

But the normal code:

```
# PRINT HEADER
print "Sample ID";
foreach(@g) { print "\t$_";}
print "\n";
```

printed:

```
cat*\t* dog*\t*     hat*\t* chair*\t* pen
```

with tab character followed by a space character between each word.

Any idea why this is happening or how to fix it?

Comment: Complete working examples please.

Comment: I see 5 spaces between words, but it could be SO translates tabs to 4 spaces, giving 5 if you had the extra.

Comment: I would print single quotes around the data, ie. `print "'\t'$_'"`

Comment: Where is the data coming from?

Comment: There's no whitespace before "cat"...was that just a copy-paste error?

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to know for sure what the problem is without seeing how you're getting the input data in the first place, but this will show you exactly what each string contains and might help you figure out what's going on:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @g = qw(cat dog hat chair pen);

for (@g) {
    printf("[%s] %vX\n", $_, $_);
}
```

Output:

```
[cat] 63.61.74
[dog] 64.6F.67
[hat] 68.61.74
[chair] 63.68.61.69.72
[pen] 70.65.6E
```

Comment: Thank you for exposing me to the printf() function; I had never heard of it before now have some reading to do. What is the meaning of those numbers in the output? I've looked over two pages describing printf that make no mention of such an output...

Comment: @Slavatron The numbers are the hex character codes for each character in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy way to dump any variable to see what's in it. In your case, maybe some hidden characters, like escape sequences. (https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Escape-Sequences.html)

```
$ perl -e 'use Data::Dumper; my @g=["cat\t", "dog\b"]; print Dumper(@g);'

$VAR1 = [
         'cat   ',
          'do'
        ];
```

Comment: Better: `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print Dumper \@g;` (represent whitespace other than spaces as escape sequences, so it's easy to distinguish between a tab and a series of spaces).